# Function pointer argument list in a class

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I have a class called A which looks like this:

```
class A
{
  protected: typedef bool(*fp)();
  public: 
  virtual void back(fp succesor,fp valid,fp solutie,fp show); // this function is defined in the .cpp
};
```

and a class B derived from A which looks like this:

```
class B : public A
{
  public: 
  bool succesor(); //defined in cpp
  bool valid(); //defined in cpp
  bool solutie(); //defined in cpp
  bool show(); //defined in cpp
  void generate()
  {
    back(succesor,valid,solutie,nullptr);
  }
};
```

I haven't shown you the constructors and the instantiation of the class, because it's not important in this phase.

The idea is that when I put that back call in the generate function is gives me these 3 errors:

1. error C3867: 'B::succesor': function call missing argument list; use '&B::succesor' to create a pointer to member
2. the same but with the other function name
3. the same but with the other function name

Please, could you suggest me where is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: `B::successor` isn't a function. It's a *member function*. It's pointer type is not `bool(*)()`, but `bool (B::*)()`.

Comment: Sorry. I've corrected the code.

Comment: Look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

Comment: @RobertEagle: No you haven't

Comment: How do you want to call your `fp` functions? What are the arguments?

Comment: I have this universal function called back.
I want to be able to reuse back along with the other derived classes B, C, D etc. 
All these derived classes are using the same back function but with different succesor,valid,solutie and show. I figured out that the best option is by using function pointers.

I don't understand at what you are referring.

Comment: You can't have function pointers, because you don't have functions. You can't use pointers-to-member-functions, because you don't have a common class type or virtual functions in a common base. You can either use templates and something like `std::bind` or `std::mem_fn`, if your calls are resolved statically, or you can wrap the dynamic dispatch into an `std::function<bool()>`.